# How to get specific fields from a django model serializer which returns all field(fields = '__all__' in serializer's meta)?

Tags: django, serialization

I have a serializer:

```
class UsrSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Usr
    fields = '__all__'
```

I don't want all fields but id, first_name, last_name and email here and don't want to modify serializer because I need all fields somewhere else:

```
org = Organization.objects.get(pk=org_id)
members = org.user_set.all()
serializer = UsrSerializer(members, many=True)
```

Comment: So from `UsrSerializer` you only want certain fields, but you don't want to change it to only include those fields? You either need to have 2 serializers, so you have the fields you want, ot just don't use the extra fields when you don't want them?

Comment: [DRF Dynamic serialzer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Like in the section of the docs that Arrakkal Abu posted about [Dynamically modifying fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields), you can remove a field from a serializer instance using `.fields.pop(field_name)`.

I'd recommend creating a reusable class like in the example, but if you're only going to do this for one instance, you could do something like:

```
serializer = UsrSerializer(members, many=True)
wanted_fields = {'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'}
all_fields = set(serializer.fields)
for field in all_fields:
    if field not in wanted_fields:
        serializer.fields.pop(field)
```